# Marca todos los campos como inválidos Template Forms

Tags: angular, formularios

agradezco su manita de ayuda. Me sucede lo siguiente:

Tengo una tabla donde una columna contiene un input y pues los datos se pintan desde un array de objetos asi:[image: columna con input]

Entonces lo que pasa es que cuando un input es inválido o valido marca a todos igual y yo solo quiero que marque al que están editando en ese momento.

Desde aquí lleno la tabla:

```
allRecords(){
this.trackingService.getRecords(payload, this.helper.getHeaders()).subscribe(
response=>{
 this.data=response;
 },
  err=>{
        this.spinner.hide();
        this.errorModal.show();
        console.error("error", err)
      });
```

}

Y asi puse el input en la tabla:

```
 <tbody id="Track">
          <tr *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
                <td>
               <form [formGroup]="tableForm">
                <input
                class="form-control"
                type="text"
                (keyup.enter)="changePanelRank($event, item)"
                [value]="item.panelRancking"
                formControlName="ranking"/>
                <small *ngIf="tableForm.invalid">No valido</small>
                </form></td>
```

Asi declare el form en el ts:

```
this.tableForm = this.fb.group({
 'ranking': new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]$/), Validator.noWhitespaceValidator])

    });
```

Como podria arreglar esto? Busqué pero no encontré un caso similiar.
Gracias.

Asi se esta viendo ahora:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero tienes que cambiar a ranking como FormArray:

```
      this.tableForm = this.fb.group({
          ranking: new FormArray([])
      });
```

Cuando obtengas los datos debes agregarlos al FormArray:

```
    allRecords(){
       this.trackingService.getRecords(payload, this.helper.getHeaders())
           .subscribe(response=>{
          this.data=response;
          // hay que crear un nuevo form control y agregarlo al FormArray
          for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++ {
            let ranking_i = new FormControl(response[i], [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]$/), Validator.noWhitespaceValidator])
            this.ranking.push(ranking_i);
          }
       },
       err=>{
         this.spinner.hide();
         this.errorModal.show();
          console.error("error", err)
       });
    }

    // agregamos el get para obtener el FormArray
    get ranking() {
        return this.tableForm.get('ranking') as FormArray;
    }
```

En el html hay que recorrer el FormArray:

```
    <form [formGroup]="tableForm">
       <div formArrayName="ranking">
          <table class="table">
             <tbody id="Track">
               <tr *ngFor="let r of ranking.controls; index as i">
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" 
                        (keyup.enter)="changePanelRank($event, r.value)"
                        [formControlName]="i" />
                 <small *ngIf="r.invalid">No valido</small>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
           </table>
         </div>
       </form>
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Estoy pensando que tu estructura de los datos que pintas en la tabla tiene la siguiente forma:

```
    clientes = [
        {
            nombre: 'Cliente 1',
            correo: 'correo1.com',
            ranking: 0,
            direccion: 'direccion 1'
        },
        {
            nombre: 'Cliente 2',
            correo: 'correo2.com',
            ranking: 0,
            direccion: 'direccion 2'
        },
        {
            nombre: 'Cliente 3',
            correo: 'correo3.com',
            ranking: 0,
            direccion: 'direccion 3'
        }
    ];
```

Cuando obtienes el ranking debes hacer alguna validación para saber que el ranking X pertenece al Cliente X

```
     allRecords(){
       this.trackingService.getRecords(payload, this.helper.getHeaders())
           .subscribe(response=>{
            this.data=response;
            
            // Estoy suponiendo que el el response y clientes tienen el mismo tamaño.
            for (let i = 0; i < this.clientes.length; i++) {
                // Aquí has de hacer la validación...
                this.clientes[i].ranking = response[i];
            }
       },
       err=>{
         this.spinner.hide();
         this.errorModal.show();
          console.error("error", err)
       });
    }
```

Ahora creamos un nuevo componente en el ejemplo le puse input-ranking. Dentro del .ts agregas lo siguiente:

```
    import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-input-ranking',
        templateUrl: './input-ranking.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./input-ranking.component.css']
    })
    export class InputRankingComponent implements OnInit {
        @Input() rankingValue: number;
        @Output() rankingModify = new EventEmitter<number>();

        rankingForm: FormGroup;

        constructor() { }

        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.rankingForm = new FormGroup({
                ranking: new FormControl(this.rankingValue, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]$/), Validator.noWhitespaceValidator])
            });
        }

        onRankingChange() {
            this.rankingModify.emit(this.rankingForm.get('ranking').value);
        }

    }
```

en el .html agregas lo siguiente:

```
    <form [formGroup]="rankingForm">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" (change)="onRankingChange()" formControlName="ranking" />
        <small *ngIf="rankingForm.invalid">No valido</small>
    </form>
```

y en el html del componente que tiene la tabla queda de la siguiente forma:

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>NOMBRE</th>
            <th>CORREO</th>
            <th>RANKING</th>
            <th>DIRECCIÓN</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="Track">
            <tr *ngFor="let cliente of clientes; index as i">
            <td>{{cliente.nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{cliente.correo}}</td>
            <td>
                <app-input-ranking [rankingValue]="cliente.ranking" (rankingModify)="cliente.ranking = $event">
                </app-input-ranking>
            </td>
            <td>{{cliente.direccion}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Si en caso de que esto no sea lo que te solucione, deberias dar mas información partes de tu código porque creo no entenderte al 100%.

Comment: Hola @AlbertoRojas gracias por tu respuesta funciona, pero quizás no especifique que cada input es parte de un row de una tabla y con tu solución me está iterando los input dentro del mismo row. Qué cambio podría hacer para lograr que solo exista un input por row?. Subire como se ve al final de la publicación.

Comment: @Ana ya agregué una actualizacion, si no es lo que esperas proporciona mas información para ayudarte.

Comment: Probe la actualización, todo funciono correcto ya me hace la validación por cada input de ranking del "cliente". Pero no entendi muy bien la finalidad del for en allrecords() si pudieras explicarme, por el momento no la utilice y al parecer no afecto en nada. @Alberto Rojas

Comment: @Ana el for es porque pensé que ya tenías un array de información y en el servicio sólo te devolvía el ranking, entonces lo puse de ejemplo para que recorrieras el array de rankings y se lo asignaras a los objetos que correspondía de tu array. Por eso el array de ejemplo que puse el ranking siempre está en 0 y con el for le asignas el valor que te devuelve el servico.

Comment: Comprendido! Muchas gracias @Alberto Rojas. Eres un crack.